# why $g(x) < \infty$ almost everywhere?

Tags: measure-theory

I have  some confusion in **RCA** book

My confusion is given below and marked in red box

[image]

My attempt  :  If $g(x) < \infty$  this  implies $x \notin A $ and $ \mu(E_k)=0$

But almost everywhere mean  that  property that doesn't hold  on set  measure $0$

so i think  $g(x) = \infty$ will converge  almost  everywhere

**My doubt** :why  $g(x) < \infty$  almost everywhere ?

Comment: $\int_{\{x: g(x)=\infty\}} gd\mu=\infty$ if $\mu (\{x: g(x)=\infty\})$ is not $0$.

Comment: yes@KaviRamaMurthy sir  if $g(x)=\infty$  that mean it doesn't hold on set measure $0$ , so$ g(x)=\infty$  almost everywhere

Comment: By definition, $g\in L^1$ means that $\int_X |g| d\mu < \infty$. As $g$ is always non-negative, this reduces to $\int_X g d\mu <\infty$. But $\int_X g d\mu$ $\geq$ $\int_{\{x:g(x)=\infty\}} g d\mu$ $ =$ $\mu(\{{x:g(x)=\infty\})$ $\cdot $ $\infty$. As such, $\mu(\{{x:g(x)=\infty\})=0$ as otherwise the integral is infinite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was pointed out in the comments, given $g\in L^1(\mu)$ we must have $g(x)<\infty$ a.e., since otherwise $g(x)=\infty$ on a measurable set $E\subset X$ with positive measure $\mu(E)>0$, and by monotonicity of the Lebesgue integral that would imply $\int|g|_X\,\text{d}\mu\ge\int_E|g|\,\text{d}\mu=\int_Eg\,\text{d}\mu=\int_E\infty\,\text{d}\mu=\infty\mu(E)=\infty$, which is a contradiction since $g\in L^1(\mu)\Rightarrow\int_X|g|\,\text{d}\mu<\infty$.